# QR Code reader for android

Tags: qr-code

i am making a qr code reader, i came across zxing lib. i was able to successfully incorporate it on my project.  however,  when using the app i noticed that it requires another application (i.e qr droid app) before i can use it, otherwise the application crashes. is there  a way that it won't require another app? or is  there other lib that i can use? thanks in advance.

in my code i just called the intent:

```
Intent qr = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
       qr.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
       startActivityForResult(qr, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it really requires the Barcode Scanner application.  Not sure if that answers your question. Second your app crashes because you are not catching ActivityNotFoundException. In Barcode Scanners open source project ZXing, you will find a module android-integration which has complete correct source code for this integration. And you will find compete source for Barcode Scanner which you could use to build scanning into your own app. Otherwise you really do want to integrate with Barcode Scanner by Intent. It is much easier.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I want to do the scanning in our own app. So i'll  probably just look for the source code  of  the Barcode Scanner. O would you happen  to know a link where  i can find it in case google won't  give me a good  result? :) super thanks.

Comment: thank you.  the apk file is the only one available for download and not the source code itself. :(

Comment: @SeanOwen How can i change the UI of the scanning page? I have to use scanner at 4 different activities. What is the best way to do that?